# How to justify section headings left in APA6 document class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, apa6

I am using the `apa6` document class for an article, but need the section headings to be justified left instead of centered. Is there a way to override this formatting so that section titles are left justified?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you want to submit an paper to a journal asked you to use class `apa6`? Then do not change the headings to avoid to get your paper not accepted. I'm not sure you are allowed to use `apa6` class to publish an article in another journal/paper, are you sure you are allowed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the base `\section` command

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
    {\b@level@one@skip}{\e@level@one@skip}%
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

to not use `\centering`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\section}% <cmd>
  {\centering}% <search>
  {\raggedright}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```